# Gravitee.io api gateway ldap auth problem

Tags: ldap, gravitee

I have problem on gravitee.io api managment.

My ldap credentials:

- Base: OU=dir1,DC=site,DC=local
- User path: CN=gravitee,OU=Service Accounts,OU=dir1,DC=site,DC=local
- Auth user path: CN=user1,OU=Users,OU=Department,OU=Departaments,OU=dir1,DC=site,DC=local

How i can write credentials?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I don't understand your question.

You have to configure LDAP access from the *gravitee.yml* within the Gravitee.io API Management (see security provider section > LDAP / AD)